# iOS app invitation landing page still links to Meta Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

When someone gets invited to use the iOS app, he lands on a web page where he can then click on a link to install the app and it also says where to report bugs and ask for feature requests.

All good and dandy, except that it's still saying to do this on Meta Stack Overflow and linking to it as well, instead to this very MSE:

> [image]

Can this please be changed to "Meta Stack Exchange" and link here, to prevent people from posting this on MSO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reminding us of this!

You should now see the page correctly updated (with version 0.1.56).

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the quick response! Just curious, isn't the web page independent i.e not related to the app version? I mean, if someone still got old app version won't he see the new landing page anyway?

Comment: Yes, it is independent; I just meant the version is an additional check you can use to make sure you have the latest.