# iOS app beta download page erroring

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, error-message, downloads

Trying to re-download the iOS app beta, and instead of the normal page with the download link, all I get is:

> {"error_id":500,"error_message":"this error has been logged","error_name":"internal_error"}

I'm referring to this page:

> [image]

<sub>(ignore the red freehand circles; image stolen from [iOS app invitation landing page still links to Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230175/ios-app-invitation-landing-page-still-links-to-meta-stack-overflow))</sub>

Comment: Yup, noticed this too and was about to report.

Comment: Maybe related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233480/im-not-receiving-push-notifications-anymore? I'm thinking it has to do with the data center move from NYC to Oregon. Obviously that will take an employee to fix and/or confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have resolved the issues around the iOS beta download page.  This was due to some reorganization that happened outside of the data center move.  Enjoy the new beta - there are a lot of new bells in the latest version.

Comment: holy cannoli there's an... achie... oh god. you just made my day